# media queries max-width for development and max-device-width for produciton

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

At the moment I develop the website using `@media screen and (max-width: 991px)` so that I can easily test by resizing my browser. But once the website has finished I replace all with `max-device-width`.

The main reason for doing is so that the user can resize the browser like they could with a fixed width website. Imagine you wanted to compare 2 website pages, you had them open in 2 windows next to each other, resized/scrolled to only show the content you needed. It would be really annoying/imposible to do this if all the media queries started to convert one into a mobile width website.

Also I notice that at: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ there is a mix of both.

So my question is will this caused any issues with twitter bootstrap?

Comment: IMO, If you don't override TW bootstrap necessary declarations (on responsive mode), No, you can use multiple media queries. Bootstrap uses `min-width` and `max-width` properties for its responsive mode.

Comment: @HashemQolami thats what I replace, all of the code in bootstrap so that it uses `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`